# I want to make a book app in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

How does  search view work .and as I'm trying to make book app so how will search view will  work if I want to find anything from 
whole app .

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with two methods,

first, make a custom search view and run a service on edit text data.

secondly, you can refer this repository for better details

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview